# Using SanDisk USB SecureAccess through Wine? If not possible, what are some good encryptions for USB between Linux and Windows?

Tags: usb, wine, encryption, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to access the encryption .exe in the SanDisk SSD via SanDiskSecureAccessV3.01_win.exe file on the USB drive and opening it through Wine, by opening it through Wine Windows Program Loader. When i try to open the .exe file this way, it initially runs the .exe, but then shows a message box saying "This application only runs on a SanDisk flash drive".

I'm assuming running it through Wine doesn't register as running it inside the flash drive. Is it possible to somehow do that?
If not possible, what's a good alternative encryption for USBs to go between Windows and Linux PCs? I saw that TrueCrypt was good, but the website says it isn't supported anymore.

Comment: Veracrypt is what replaced Truecrypt a loooong time ago. And no, you can't use that SanDisk software with wine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest option that I have found is to use a VeraCrypt container on an NTFS or exFAT-formatted USB stick. The container itself should also be formatted as either NTFS or exFAT so that it can be read by Windows and Linux (macOS and FreeBSD can also work with these partition types).

Depending on the purpose of the container, I also have one or two plaintext files that are visible to the world and a directory:

- `reward.txt`, which has my contact information in the event the USB device is lost and someone finds it
- `password.txt`, which usually says something like:

  ```
  The password is that silly phrase with the numbers I had you save in a note on your phone
  ```

  This is only done for encrypted containers that have things my family might want access to after my passing, such as edited home videos and whatnot.
- `/setup`, which has the VeraCrypt binaries so that I can install the necessary tools to access the container from another machine if necessary

With this setup I've been able to securely move and share files between systems, family, and colleagues.